# No Visible @interface error in ios

Tags: ios

Im getting the following **issue** in ios how to clear and run the code successfully.

The issue is:

`"No visible @interface for 'ViewController' declares the selector 'performSelector:afterDelay:'".`

Comment: I presume there is some code?

Comment: Errors like that are usually that the selector being asked to be performed isn't visible to the compiler in that file ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such function `performSelector:afterDelay:`.

Looking at the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector%3awithObject%3aafterDelay%3a) the only function that includes "performSelector" and "afterDelay" is...

```
performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:
```

and

```
performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:inModes:
```